# asp.net 5, logout in the controller when met some condition

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to logout in the controller when met some condition,

My idea is redirect to "/Identity/Account/Logout"

What I tried but not work

```
return RedirectToAction("Logout", "Account");
```

The ordinary code is:

```
public IActionResult Home_Index()
       {
           var Crm_Account_Data = _context.Crm_Account.Where(x => x.Crm_Email.Equals(User.Identity.Name)).FirstOrDefault();
           if (Crm_Account_Data != null)
           {
              return View();
           }
           else
           {
               // Logout
               // return RedirectToAction("Logout", "Account");
           }
       }
```

Comment: Can you share your `Logout` action and the error you get now?

Comment: What do you mean *not work*?

Comment: By your title, do you mean **ASP.NET MVC 5** (on the full/classic .NET Framework) - or are you referring to **ASP.NET Core 5 MVC** (on the newer, crossplatform .NET Core Framework). Please make this absolutely clear!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating two action methods. Login() and Logout()
Your Login action would be something like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        if (!IsValidUser)
        {
            //redirect to login view
        }

        if (IsValidUser)
        {
            //executables (perhaps passing a model)
        }
        return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```